# Jinja2 Template: Nested for and if condition problem

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have to write a shell script based on a series of "if and for" conditions (nested) written in jinja2 (to be used in ansible).

The problem is that an error of "**undefined variable: webroot**" is returned and I don't understand why.

This is the jinja2 code (under **templates folder**):

```
#!/bin/bash
certbot certonly -n --webroot
{% for hosting in hostings %}
{%   if inventory_hostname in hosting.servers %}
   -w {{ hosting.webroot }}
{%     for domain in hosting.domains %}
         -d {{ domain }}
{%     endfor %}
{%   endif %}
{% endfor %}
#-m {{ hosting.letsencrypt_email }} --agree-tos
-m info@email.it --agree-tos
```

Variable "webroot" exist in a vars/main.yml and it's the same of the "servers" variable that is correctly scoped.

**vars/main.yml file:**

```
hostings:
 - name: 'Wottts'
   servers:
     - 'w2.test.it'
     - 'w.test.it'
     - 'w.yat.it'
   template: 'template.conf.j2'
   webroot: '/var/www/test/html'
   domains:
     - 'pippus.invalid'
     - 'www.pippus.invalid'
```

The error is **fatal: [host.name.it]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'webroot' is undefined"}**

Thanks for any help/suggestion.

Comment: Your best bet to try and parse through why its not showing the way you think, especially since you don't think the error is on the servers variable, would be to make the template print to somewhere as a test, but print the entire hosting variable out into the template just to make sure that it is not dragging in something you are not expecting (like maybe you are duplicating the use of a variable somewhere so you aren't pulling in what you thought you were).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **solved** it by myself!

The problem was on the penultimate line:

```
...
{% endfor %}
#-m {{ hosting.letsencrypt_email }} --agree-tos
-m info@email.it --agree-tos
```

Seems that the line that started with the "**#**" character was the problem, removing it the variables are correctly recognized.